# Metrics Zip File In eclipse not Imported Properly

Tags: java, eclipse, metrics

I intend to use the Java Metrics library for performance testing. I downloaded the package from https://github.com/codahale/metrics/downloads as a zip file in Ubuntu. I had put it in my java build path in eclipse by selecting add external jars. When I write in my code import com.yammer.metrics.core, I can't seem to access any of the classes in the core package, should I have converted the file I downloaded as a jar file or is there another way around this? Any help would be much appreciated.